# Getting numbers out of string that are seperated by a space or comma

Tags: java, regex, string, validation

Given a string containing numbers that are separated by either white space or a comma, how do you extract the numbers into an array? A caveat is I'm not sure if it would split things into too many parts if I were to try and split on whitespace OR commas.

```
Scanner sc = Scanner.(System.IN);
String input = sc.nextLine();
double numbers[] = (double)input.split(",|\s");
```

An example of `input` would be

```
4 5 9

2,3,7

8,2 1

5, 3, 4, 5
```

and the result would be an array containing each number assigned to an element of the array. But the following should not be allowed
`4,,2`
`,1,2,3`
`4,5,`

However a user may make a mistake input something not a letter (e.g. type 'q' instead of 1) and I would like to use `try` and `catch` but I'm not sure how this would look since `.split()` returns an array.

Comment: split() on String returns String[], this is well documented.. what is the confusion ?

Comment: @sanbhat I know that, what is the question?

Comment: from your code you are expecting double[], so its better you restate your question with possible input and expected output for clarity

Comment: Yes that is why I cast using `(double)`. Just so you know I know the code doesn't work, that is why I'm here. I updated, is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split by any number of whitespaces or commas and then parse every resulting String to a number:

```
String[] numberParts = input.split("[\\s,]+");
double[] doubles = new double[numberParts.length];
int i=0;
for (String part : numberParts) {
   double value = Double.parseDouble(part);
   doubles[i++] = value;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind [\\s,]+ ?

Comment: @Celeritas - [\\s,] is a character class composed of all whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc) and the comma character. X+ means X, one or more times. combined the meaning is one or more of whitespace or comma characters. for more information see the javadoc for Pattern - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Thanks, one thing unclear is why is there two slashes? \s is matching whitespace so what does the first slash do? \\ is one backslash (\) so how does the regex engine know we want to match whitespace and not a backslash?

Comment: @Celeritas - youre passing the pattern argument as a java String literal. the syntax for java string literals treats backslashes in a special way - think "\n". so "\\" as part of a java string literal ends up being a single backslash in the actual string.

Answer (score 2):

How about replace all non-numeric first (except the seperator)? It is better to make the separator to 1 fixed value.

you can try like this:

```
//replace ',' with 'space' so that you only have 1 type of separator
input=input.replaceAll(","," ").replaceAll("[a-zA-Z!@#.:;$%?|^\\&*/()+=-]+","");
double numbers[] = (double)input.split("\\s"); //or split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what the input is exactly or the format but from what you just described you will have to use a combination of the split(" ")/split(",") function and then convert the string to an double via Double.parseDouble("1234").

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
    String line="1 2 3 55,56 , 8989 , 88.00 , -76.08 , -6 , +4";
String REGEX=" |,";
String res[]=line.split(REGEX);
double numbers[]=new double[res.length];
int i=0;
for(String val:res){
    if(!val.isEmpty()&& val.matches("[+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))
        numbers[i++]=Double.parseDouble(val);
}
for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
    System.out.println(numbers[j]);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
55.0
56.0
8989.0
88.0
-76.08
-6.0
4.0
```